# Oracle SQL -Need to Extract String between delimiters

Tags: sql, oracle

I need an Oracle SQL statement to extract text from between each delimiters from below example,

`NA$Sales$India/Blore$Hardware$Sold`

Output should return in different columns

```
Region     Department     Country        Product_type    Status
NA         Sales          India/Blore    Hardware        Sold
```

i tried below statement but it only returns the string after the first delimiter

```
SUBSTR('NA$Sales$India/Blore$Hardware$Sold', INSTR('NA$Sales$India/Blore$Hardware$Sold','$')+1, 
        INSTR('NA$Sales$India/Blore$Hardware$Sold','$') + INSTR('NA$Sales$India/Blore$Hardware$Sold','$')+ LENGTH(NA$Sales$India/Blore$Hardware$Sold)) AS test
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to use regular expressions.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'NA$Sales$India/Blore$Hardware$Sold' from dual)
```

Query:

```
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '([^\$]+)', 1, 1) region,
  4         regexp_substr(col, '([^\$]+)', 1, 2) department,
  5         regexp_substr(col, '([^\$]+)', 1, 3) country,
  6         regexp_substr(col, '([^\$]+)', 1, 4) product_type,
  7         regexp_substr(col, '([^\$]+)', 1, 5) status
  8  from test;

REGION     DEPARTMENT      COUNTRY     PRODUCT_TYPE    STATUS
---------- --------------- ----------- --------------- --------
NA         Sales           India/Blore Hardware        Sold

SQL>
```

---

Or, if you prefer `substr + instr` combination (with same sample data):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'NA$Sales$India/Blore$Hardware$Sold' from dual)
```

Query:

```
  3  select
  4  substr(col, 1, instr(col, '$', 1, 1) - 1) region,
  5  substr(col, instr(col, '$', 1, 1) + 1,
  6              instr(col, '$', 1, 2) - instr(col, '$', 1, 1) - 1
  7        ) department,
  8  substr(col, instr(col, '$', 1, 2) + 1,
  9              instr(col, '$', 1, 3) - instr(col, '$', 1, 2) - 1
 10        ) country,
 11  substr(col, instr(col, '$', 1, 3) + 1,
 12              instr(col, '$', 1, 4) - instr(col, '$', 1, 3) - 1
 13        ) product_type,
 14  substr(col, instr(col, '$', 1, 4) + 1) status
 15  from test;

REGION     DEPARTMENT      COUNTRY     PRODUCT_TYPE    STATUS
---------- --------------- ----------- --------------- --------
NA         Sales           India/Blore Hardware        Sold

SQL>
```

Comment: I have used Substr & Instr to get the results but regexp looks much simpler

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEX_SUBSTR` to extract the text delimited by dollar signs. Note that the dollar sign must be escaped with '\$' in the regular expression as it has a special meaning (end of line). The last parameter of `REGEX_SUBSTR` determines which so called *group* to extract. (Groups are denoted with parentheses.)

```sql
select
    regexp_substr(text, '^(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)$', 1, 1, 'i', 1) "Region",
    regexp_substr(text, '^(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)$', 1, 1, 'i', 2) "Department",
    regexp_substr(text, '^(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)$', 1, 1, 'i', 3) "Country",
    regexp_substr(text, '^(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)$', 1, 1, 'i', 4) "Product_type",
    regexp_substr(text, '^(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)\$(.*)$', 1, 1, 'i', 5) "Status"
from (
    select 'NA$Sales$India/Blore$Hardware$Sold' text
    from dual
);
```

And the result is:

| Region | Department | Country | Product_type | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NA | Sales | India/Blore | Hardware | Sold |